# What exactly does earn you Robocop Hat.?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

I was searching Robocop Hat details but I found none. The description in the Winter Bash states "complete 5 reviews each in at least 5 queues". SO what does it excatly mean. What is 5 reviews in 5 queues.? Importantly, what are queues.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you reach a certain rep threshold, you'll unlock the privilege to [access the review queues.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) Here's what I see on our [review page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review):

> [image: Some queues: close votes, low quality posts, reopen votes and suggested edits]

I only see four queues right now, since first posts and late answers aren't showing up.

To earn the Robocop hat, in five different queues you'll have to do five reviews each. That *does* mean only certain users will be able to earn this hat.

Comment: Yeah, those two queues don't exist on MSO (they should on most other sites though).

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks, I didn't know that!

Comment: Don't you have to make 5 reviews per queue, not just one? Help text is `complete 5 reviews each in at least 5 queues` and I certainly needed 5 per queue to get it

Comment: @Gagravarr Good point, I misread it.

Answer (score 3):

That's referring to the [review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review) linked in the top bar.  In this context a queue is just a list (of posts that need reviewed for various reasons).

Comment: That means users not having access to 5 queues will never earn this hat.?

Comment: @Akshat Not this Winter Bash.

Comment: Okay.. Although not so fair..!!

Comment: @Akshat It's not the only hat some people can't earn, either. There's one for participating in closing/deletion, one for reopening, another for making your first post, etc.